# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate? how "hide" button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a standingStatus.Text = "ADMIN";(in cs) If this is the admin, then how do I hide the first 3 buttons, please give advice

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operations" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridInfButton}" x:Name="infButton">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Information" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridPlayButton}" x:Name="playButton">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="PlayOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridEditButton}" Margin="5 0 0 0" x:Name="editButton">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="PencilOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridRemoveButton}" Margin="5 0 0 0" x:Name="removeButton" IsEnabled="False">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="DeleteOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource gridEyeButton}" Margin="5 0 0 0" x:Name="eyeButton">
                                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="EyeOutline" Style="{StaticResource gridButtonIcon}"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I tried to do it in various ways, but nothing worked out for me

type here

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Visibility = "{Binding IsAdmin}"` in the button declaration in the xaml and create a property `public Visibility IsAdmin {get;set;}` which is notifying when changed (if you use MVVM it should be easy). If you don't use MVVM, you can create a class :

```
public class NotifyingProperty<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private T _property;

    public T Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set 
        { 
            _property = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public NotifyingProperty()
    {
        this._property = default;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then in the window backend create a property `public NotifyingProperty<Visibility> IsAdmin {get;set;}` and set it whenever the text is changed.

NOTE : in this case, you have to change `"{Binding IsAdmin}"` to "`{Binding IsAdmin.Property}"`

Also, don't forget to call `DataContext = this;` in both cases.